# How to Identify type of Recurrence Event like weakly,yearly or Daily?

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model

Using Client context I want to get all Recurrence Event.
I use

`var recurrenceData = oListItem["RecurrenceData"];`

but it return `<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><weekly mo=\"TRUE\" weekFrequency=\"1\" /></repeat><repeatInstances>3</repeatInstances></rule></recurrence>"`

Then How to Identify this Event is weakly / yearly /Daily ?

Comment: try to use List.asmx instead https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/how-get-calendar-recurrent-events-by-csom-from-sharepoint-2013/